# Some simple inequalities on factorials

Tags: number-theory, inequality, factorial

How can I prove the following inequalities for factorials in an elemantary way:

$$ n^{\frac{n}{2}} \leq n! $$

$$ n^{\frac{2n}{3}} \leq n! $$

$$ \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^{n} \leq n! $$

Usage of stirling approximation is not allowed. Thank you.

Edit: You can show the truth of the second inequality for $n>k$ with a information that contains what is $k$.

Comment: denotes $x$ here a natural number?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes.

Comment: The second inequality is wrong for $x = 10$: $10! = 3628800 < 4.64 \times 10^6 \approx 10^{20/3}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Point 1.* Fix $n$, then
$$
(n!)^2=(1\cdot n) \cdot (2\cdot (n-1)) \cdot (3 \cdot (n-3)) \cdots (n \cdot 1)
$$
and each factor in bracket is at least $n$.

*Point 3.* Fix $n=3k$ (the other cases can be done similarly), then
\begin{align}
(3k)!&\ge (3k)(3k-1) \cdots (k) \\
&= (2k)\prod_{i=1}^k (2k+i)(2k-i)\\
&\ge (2k)\prod_{i=1}^k (2k+k)(2k-k)\\
&=(2k)(3k^2)^k= (2\cdot 3^k) k^{3k}.
\end{align}

Comment: Is it meant to be $(n!)^2$ on the left of the displayed equation?

Comment: It depends on which point you stop: I was thinking on the middle so that we have a reordering of the factors; however I will make it explicit, thank you

Comment: I agree it works as you had it, if one stops halfway.

Comment: But your way is better since there is no need to make explicit the case $n$ odd (where there is a central element in the product)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the second and third inequalities?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti What did you mean by fix? Thank you.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I edited the question.

Comment: @BrightChancellor You can find also the solution of point 3

Answer (score 1):

Inequality 2 holds for $n \ge 12$ (but not before that except $n=1.$)

First let $a_n=n^{2n},\ b_n=(n!)^3,$ so you want $a_n \le b_n.$

For $n=12:$ $a_{12}=0794....,\ b_{12}=1099...,$ where the sections after the dots have the same number of digits.

Now $a_{n+1}/a_n=(1+1/n)^{2n} \cdot (n+1)^2,$ while $b_{n+1}/b_n=(n+1)^3.$ Here $(1+1/n)^{2n} \to e^2$ from below, so at any rate is less than $8.$ Since we're working with $n \ge 12$ the inductive step wanted is now $8(n+1)^2 \le (n+1)^3$ and holds.

Comment: Beautiful approach, thanks a lot for this proof of inequality 2.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative we can prove by induction, that is for $n!\ge n^{\frac{n}{2}}$

**base case**

- $n=1 \implies 1\le 1$

**induction step**

$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!=(n+1)n^{\frac{n}{2}}\stackrel{?}\ge (n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$

$(n+1)n^{\frac{n}{2}}\ge (n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \iff n^{\frac{n}{2}}\ge (n+1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \iff n^n\ge (n+1)^{n-1}\\\iff n\,n^{n-1}\ge (n+1)^{n-1}\iff n\ge \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$

which is true for $n=1$, $n=2$ by inspection and $n\ge 3$ since $RHS <3$.

Comment: Even if you can calculate the limit without Stirling approximation, this does not ensure that the inequalities hold for all $n$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti oh yes of course, we need to prove for all n!

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti what about now, by proving that they are decreasing?

Comment: Very usefull, clever +1

Comment: @gimusi: that would be enough, surely, but I don't know if it is true..

Comment: As I found Paolo's answer more elemantary and simple, I choose his answer, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BrightChancellor I fully agree, mine is not conclusive at all, I need to work on it more! Thanks, Bye!

Comment: Wow, beautiful, thank you!

Comment: It is less cleaver but it seems to work, let try also for 3. I’ll do it later.